# how to update grid parameters for figure & canvas created with matplotlib.figure & matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.11, matplotlib-widget, matplotlib-gridspec

I need to update grid parameters (visible, which, axis, **kwargs) to customize the major and minor grid lines style. i tried using `plt.grid(which='minor', linewidth=0.5, linestyle='dotted')` but it did not work; it only works if figure and subplot was created using `matplotlib.pyplot.subplots()`.

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as Canvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure    

class MatplotlibWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):   
    self.canvas = Canvas(Figure(figsize=(8, 6)))
    self.axes = self.canvas.figure.subplots()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got this working by invoking grid() method of the axes to configure grid lines. refer to documentation here:
[matplotlib.axes.Axes.grid](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.grid.html)

`axes.grid(which='minor', linewidth=0.5, linestyle='dotted')`